# customize url in yii

Tags: php, yii, yii-url-manager

I have a url like this `LriIndustries/Companies/id/2` where I would like to convert it into `company/id/2`

I have made this change in the config main

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'showScriptName'=>false,
    'caseSensitive' =>true,
    'rules'=>array(
           'LriIndustries/Companies'=>'comapny/id/2',
```

when i have changed the url in the view from

```
<?php echo CHtml::link('read more',array('lriCompany/NewsDetail','id'=>$values->news_id));?>    

<?php echo CHtml::link('read more',array('comapny','id'=>$values->news_id));?>
```

It was redirecting to a 404 error page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
'rules'=>array(
           'company/id/<id:\d+>/*' =>'LriIndustries/Companies/',
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Your rule should be:

```
'company/id/<id:\d+>' => 'LriIndustries/Companies',
```

And you should't change parameters for creating url in view:

```
echo CHtml::link('read more',array('lriCompany/NewsDetail','id'=>$values->news_id));
```

This is rigth way to create url.